# generic solution for storing messages in app

Tags: c#, silverlight

What is a common way to store messages in app(texts of warnings, text of dialogs etc) in C#? How do you guys do it?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard .NET framework localization mechanism. See [Localizing Silverlight-based Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). If you don't have to support multiple languages, you just have all your resources for default culture. This will enable you to easily add translations to other languages in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Create Table in database - fist way

```
id 
Message
Type  - 1=waring,2-error
```

Create XML - second way

```
  <Element id=1>
    <Message> dsjafkdsa </Message>
    <Type> 1/2 </Type>
  </Element>
```

Comment: hm. And how do I get the message? parsing XML each time?

Comment: @Eugeny89 - make use of linq to xml api

Comment: I'm not sure that's the easiest solution

Comment: @Eugeny89 - go for the localization of resources